# How do I make a custom back button and action in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I am trying to make a custom back button in swift although it never changes, I am slo trying to make the back button do an action and perform a function. The code where I am at:

```
var doneButton = UIImage(named: "arrow2.png")
        var topLeftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: doneButton, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("backToList"))
        topLeftButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = topLeftButton  //nothing happens


func backToList(){

    saveData()// nothing runs
}
```

I want to be able to change the back button to my own UIImage and make a selector action happens once clicked.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add an UIImage instead of a button with the picture wanted and add a "Tap Gesture Recognizer" by dragging it to the UIImage. Also, don't forget to enable user interaction under the Attributes section of the image (see image below)
[image]

**After that** you control drag your UIImage into the code and create the action with your desired function.

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldnt work for a back button?  this is more for a bar button item in the left hand corner?

Comment: Sorry I'm really confused how you can change a back button by changing the nav bar button and dismissing the view controller....